# How do I convert the complex number $-2e^{2j \omega } + 4e^{j \omega }-3$ into polar form?

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I convert the complex number $-2e^{2j \omega } + 4e^{j \omega }-3$ into polar form: $re^{j\theta}$

The reason I am doing this is because I want to determine the phase of this complex number and it is easier to determine the phase by converting to polar form first.

Comment: Can you convert each of the pieces into Cartesian form?

Comment: Yes, by using Euler's trig identity

Comment: Then do so, add them up, and convert the single complex number to polar.  Polar form is not handy for addition.  It will depend on $\omega$.  You will get the arctan of an expression of sines and cosines.

Comment: I get $$atan(\frac{2sin(2\omega)+4sin(\omega)}{-2cos(2\omega)+4cos(\omega)-3})$$

Comment: You lost a  a minus sign on the first sin in the numerator but the approach is correct.  You also have to deal with the fact that the range of atan is $(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2) $ and you might have to add $\pi$ to it.  There is also the stray chance the denominator is zero.  Computer languages have a function atan2 that takes care of the quadrants and zero.  As you are using $j$ instead of $i$ I imagine you are in engineering so would be interested in the computer aspect.